# Is it possible to override material-ui components default props?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Lets say I want every `Button` component from `material-ui` to have default props of `variant="contained" color="secondary"`. Is this possible?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The documentation for this is here: https://material-ui.com/customization/globals/#default-props

Here is an example of how to do this in v4 (v5 example further down):

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import {createMuiTheme, MuiThemeProvider, Button} from "@material-ui/core";

const theme = createMuiTheme({
  props: {
    MuiButton: {
      variant: "contained",
      color: "secondary"
    }
  }
});
function App() {
  return (
    <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <Button>Props defaulted</Button>
    </MuiThemeProvider>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

[image: Edit default props]

---

Here's a similar example, but with the theme structure for v5 of Material-UI:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import Button from "@mui/material/Button";
import { createTheme, ThemeProvider } from "@mui/material/styles";

const theme = createTheme({
  components: {
    MuiButton: {
      defaultProps: {
        variant: "contained",
        color: "secondary"
      }
    }
  }
});
function App() {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <Button>Props defaulted</Button>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

[image: Edit default props]

Comment: Is there a way to modify the default properties conditionally? Say I want to set custom `spacing` only for `<Grid container>` but not for `<Grid item>`.

Comment: @PavelLobodinský No, there is no way to do that with `defaultProps`. It is possible to get a similar effect via `styleOverrides` in the theme since that can accept a callback that receives the props passed to the component and can vary the styles based on that.

Answer (score 0):

Create your own component `<MyButton />` which renders a `<Button>` component from `material-ui`. Style the component as you wish and use `MyButton` in your code.

Comment: I want to avoid doing this to every component that i want to change

Comment: Is using a HOC (higher order component) an option for you?

Comment: It looks like there is no option to do what i want and i will have to go with your solution

Comment: As per @Ryan Cogswell's answer, it seems there is a way though :)

Answer (score -1):

If I understood the question correctly, you have to set that when you instantiate your theme :

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  overrides: {
    MuiButton: {
      root: {
        fontSize: '1rem',
      },
    },
  },
});
```

Comment: This will not override `backgroundColor` and other props that gets overrided by the component