# Is there a way to change Typography defaults in a component?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

The default variant and color of the [Typography component](https://material-ui.com/api/typography/#props) is `body1` and `initial`. I've made a component, and when the Typography component is used as children of it, I'd like the default to instead be `body2` and `textSecondary`. Is there a way to do this in Material UI?

```
<Sidebar>
  <Typography>
    This should have body2 and textSecondary 
    when nothing else is specified.
  </Typography>
</Sidebar>

<Typography>
  This should have the regular defaults.
</Typography>
```

I can of course do the following, but would really prefer a way where the child components could still use the regular Typography component. Or if there's a way to extend/create an alternative Typography component that doesn't result in two components like here (the wrapper and the wrapped typography component).

```
import React from 'react';
import Typography, { TypographyProps } from 'components/Typography';

export default function SidebarTypography({
  variant = 'body2',
  color = 'textSecondary',
  ...props
}: TypographyProps): React.ReactElement {
  return <Typography variant={variant} color={color} {...props} />;
}
```

```
<Sidebar>
  <SidebarTypography>
    This has body2 and textSecondary.
  </SidebarTypography>
</Sidebar>

<Typography>
  This has the regular defaults.
</Typography>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to override material-ui components default props?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57359439/is-it-possible-to-override-material-ui-components-default-props)

Comment: You can have `Sidebar` wrap its children in a `ThemeProvider` that sets defaults for those props.

Comment: @RyanCogswell That looks promising, yes. But when using a `ThemeProvider` and `createMuiTheme` like that, does it completely override the existing theme, or does it only change what I specify? I.e. would I need to include everything I've specified in the App theme as well, or can I only specify the overrides I want?

Comment: You can extend the outer theme by providing a function. https://material-ui.com/customization/theming/#nesting-the-theme

Comment: And here you can see the specifics of what the library does in that case: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.8.3/packages/material-ui-styles/src/ThemeProvider/ThemeProvider.js#L55.

Comment: Using `ThemeProvider` _and_ a nested theme seems to have worked great, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved using a combination of the suggested duplicate ([Is it possible to override material-ui components default props?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57359439/39321)), and the "nested themes" feature (https://material-ui.com/customization/theming/#nesting-the-theme) I didn't know about.

```
const sidebarTheme = (theme) =>
  createMuiTheme({
    ...theme,
    props: {
      ...theme.props,
      MuiTypography: {
        color: 'textSecondary',
        variant: 'body2',
      },
    },
  });

export default function SideBar(props) {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={sideBarTheme}>{props.children}</ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

Comment: thank you! Your answer helped me to figure out how to have a multiple themes for my website. A main theme that sets all colors etc. and sub themes that can override those. This way I can add or change elements of my main theme without breaking the other colors scheme themes.

Answer (score 1):

You can also override globally like this any variant of MuiTypography.

```
import { createMuiTheme, MuiThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
```

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  overrides: {
    MuiTypography: {
      body1: {
        fontSize: '18px !important',
        color: 'red',
      },
    },
  },
});
```

```
 <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}> 
        // Your pages...
 </MuiThemeProvider>
```

Answer (score -3):

```
<Typography variant="h1" component="h2">
  h1. Heading
</Typography>
```