# How can I set height of items in material design globally?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I would like to set size to 50% of current size in material ui.

For tables, for cards components, buttons..

Is there any way how can I do it globaly?

The class name looks dynamic `MuiTableBody-root-614`..

Comment: What version of Material-UI are you using? When you say "size", what "size" are you referring to? font-size? height?

Comment: I am using `3.8.3`. Height of row I would like to set it to 2x smaller http://prntscr.com/str9kx , for Example for CARD component

Comment: You have better options available in v4 via `Table` props (e.g. `size="small"` or `padding="none"`) which can be set [globally via the theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57359439/is-it-possible-to-override-material-ui-components-default-props/57360023#57360023). The default Material-UI styles are also easier to customize in v4 because the class names are no longer dynamic  (e.g. `MuiTableBody-root` instead of `MuiTableBody-root-614`).

Comment: Where can I find names like `MuiButton` if the name component is `Button`? What should I set for `CardActions` component?

Comment: It's always "Mui" + ComponentName, but you can also find it in the API docs: https://material-ui.com/api/button/#component-name.

Comment: For `CardActions`, you would need to override the [padding](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.10.1/packages/material-ui/src/CardActions/CardActions.js#L11).